# How many kills do you need to get before leveling up a trait in Star Wars Battlefront?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront

I've only recently gotten a trait, and don't often get them even to level two, how many kills do I need to get to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's one level every three kills but you lose one level every death.